# libdef for the assert interface for Chai

Tags: javascript, chai, flowtype

Using Flow `0.35.0`, the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) libdef that is available for [chai](http://chaijs.com/) (available [here](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/chai_v3.5.x/flow_v0.24.0-/chai_v3.5.x.js)) don't seem to support the assert interface.

So I decided to declare it myself for my own project since I make use of only half a dozen assert functions.

The below is what I did and is working fine:

```
 declare class ChaiAssert {
     isFalse       (o: any)        : boolean;    
     instanceOf    (x: any, t: any): boolean;
     isNumber      (x: any)        : boolean;
     isString      (x: any)        : boolean;
     isTrue        (x: any)        : boolean;
     isNull        (x: any)        : boolean;
     throws        (f:   F)        : boolean;
 }
```

… and in my code the declaration is used as follows:

```
const assert: ChaiAssert = require('chai').assert;
```

Like I said, this is working but is unsatisfactory as it forces me to define an arbitrary name for the `assert` object and also does not declare `chai` as a module.

Trying to imitate some of the approaches discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1806) I tried the following which is also working:

```
declare class AssertClass {
     static isFalse       (o: any)        : void;    
     static instanceOf    (x: any, t: any): void;
     static isNumber      (x: any)        : void;
     static isString      (x: any)        : void;
     static isTrue        (x: any)        : void;
     static isNull        (x: any)        : void;
     static throws        (f:   F)        : void;
}

 declare export var assert: typeof AssertClass
```

… and in my code the import statement is using the more idiomatic syntax (which was not possible with the previous approach) as follows:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
```

But I've no idea whether this is the right way to declare the `assert` object exported by `chai` (apart from the fact that it seems to be working).

For instance I declare in my libdef an imaginary class `AssertClass` with some static methods. However, I've no idea whether that's the way the `assert` object that `chai` exports is implemented --- whether it is instance of any class, let alone if that class has static methods. I tried to look at the code but failed to parse it.

So my questions are:

1. is the above approach right / acceptable?
2. if so, do I have to further annotate the `assert` object at the point it is imported. The following seems to be both unnecessary and a syntax error:

   ```
   import {assert: AssertClass} from 'chai';
   ```